# fix over exposure in importance sampling in screen space reflections

Tags: rendering, brdf, real-time, reflection

I am having my first encounter with the rendering of indirect reflections in the form of screen space reflections in a game engine, but i am struggling to get correct looking results.

[image: taken at low resolution and ray count]

(patterns arise from a bad way of generating noise for montecarlo integration)

(image taken at low ray count. otherwise the color values end up going to NaN)

From what i've gathered, a common formulation of the rendering equation is as follows:

$$L_o(p,\omega_o)=L_e(p,\omega_o)+\int_{\Omega}L_i(p,\omega_i)fr(\omega_i,\omega_o)(n\cdot\omega_i)d\omega_i$$

which, dropping the $L_e(p,\omega_o)$ term, can be approximated using the following monte carlo estimator:

$$L_o(p,\omega_o)\approx\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{L_i(p,\omega_i)fr(\omega_i,\omega_o)(n\cdot\omega_i)}{p(\omega_i)}$$

where $n$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the surface.

for actual computation of values, all of these terms must be specified.

$L_i(p,\omega_i)$ is found through raymarching in screen space

$fr(\omega_i,\omega_o)$ is the Cook-Torrance BRDF:$\frac{FGD}{4(n\cdot\omega_i)(n\cdot\omega_o)}$

if we name the angle between $n$ and $m$ $\theta$, we get that the GGX NDF is:$D=\frac{\alpha^2}{\pi(\cos^2(\theta)(\alpha^2-1)+1)^2}$

where $m$ is the microfacet normal $m=\frac{\omega_i+\omega_o}{|\omega_i+\omega_o|}$

$p(\omega_i)$ Is the PDF that can be derived from the GGX NDF $\frac{\alpha^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\pi(\cos^2(\theta)(\alpha^2-1)+1)^2}$

When put all together we get:

$$L_o(p,\omega_o)\approx\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{L_i(p,\omega_i)\frac{FG}{4(n\cdot\omega_i)(n\cdot\omega_o)}\frac{\alpha^2}{\pi(\cos^2(\theta)(\alpha^2-1)+1)^2}(n\cdot\omega_i)}{\frac{\alpha^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\pi(\cos^2(\theta)(\alpha^2-1)+1)^2}}$$

After simplifying, we get:

$$L_o(p,\omega_o)\approx\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{L_i(p,\omega_i)FG}{4(n\cdot\omega_o)\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$$

This procedure seems correct to me but the images produced by my implementation have over exposed reflections at sharp incidence angles or at low roughness values. However, when i remove the $\sin(\theta)$ factor from the denominator it looks plausible (not sure about correctness though).

[image: taken at low resolution with no denoise solution]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing and some research I have found that both the $\sin(\theta)$ and the $\cos(\theta)$ should be removed from the denominator.

the reasoning is that, since we want a probability function of steradians instead of angles, the $\sin(\theta)$ factor (which is essentially used to convert from steradians on a unit sphere to radians on the two polar axis) should be dropped.

Also, $\cos(\theta)$ (as Nathan Reed explains in [this](http://reedbeta.com/blog/hows-the-ndf-really-defined/) blog post) is there to convert from microfacet area to macrosurface area. Since we are generating microsurface samples, this should be removed.

After these corrections we get the formula

$$L_o(p,\omega_o)\approx\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{L_i(p,\omega_i)FG}{4(n\cdot\omega_o)}$$

which is free of the artifacts of the formula on the question.